# How do I use symbolic references in Perl?

Tags: perl, variables

In Perl, if a variable holds the name for another variable, how do I use the first variable to visit the other one?

For example, let

```
$name = "bob";
@bob = ("jerk", "perlfan");
```

how should I use $name to get to know what kind of person bob is?
Although I'm not quite sure, my vague memory tells me it might related to typeglob.

Comment: Why not use `{bob => [qw(jerk perlfan)], alice =>[qw(alien)]}->{bob}` (i.e. use a HASH where "bob" is one key)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Several points:

- You aren't talking about typeglobs, you are talking about **symbolic references**.
- Don't use symbolic references -- they lead to hard to track down bugs.
- In almost any case where symbolic references seem like a good idea, using a data structure based on a hash is the best approach.
- Consider using Hash::Util to lock your hashes when you don't want to alter them.
- Symbolic references don't work on lexical variables.
- Typeglobs don't work on lexical variables.
- Use lexical variables.
- Don't use symbolic references.

See [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for more on references (symbolic and otherwise).
See [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) for help using data structures.
See [perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Symbol-Tables) for more on typeglobs.
See [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Private-Variables-via-my()) for more on lexical variables.

Here's an example of using locked hashes to control access to data based on the content of a variable:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Hash::Util qw( lock_hash unlock_hash );

my %data;
lock_hash( %data );
#Altering %data is a fatal exception.

unlock_hash( %data );

%data = (
    'bob' => [ 'jerk', 'genius' ],
);
lock_hash( %data );


for my $name (qw/ bob  margaret /) {
    my $info = $data{$name}; # Fatal error when accessing data for margaret.
    print "$name is a\n";
    print map "\t$_\n", @$info;
}
```

All warnings aside, the syntax to use symbolic references should you need to use it (but you won't) is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $name = 'bob';

our @bob = qw/jerk genius/;

my $qualities;

{   no strict 'refs';
    print "$name: ", @$name, "\n";
    $qualities = \@$name;
}

print "$name is a @$qualities\n";
```

Note that the array `@bob` is declared with `our`.  Symbolic references only work with values in the symbol table.  In other words, lexical variables do not work with symbolic references.

Just in case I haven't emphasized this enough, ***don't use symbolic references***.

Comment: Exactly. You easily could have stopped after the second bullet. I edited the question's title accordingly.

Comment: +1 for a technically correct and amazingly comprehensive explanation of how to do it and why not to.

Answer (score 13):

This is very bad practice. If you **ever** need to do it, it means you should refactor your code. Perhaps a hash with named keys would be better:

```
my %data = (
    'bob' => [ 'jerk', 'perlfan' ],
);
my $name = 'bob';

print $data{ $name }->[0], "\n";
print $data{ $name }->[1], "\n";

my $stringified = join ' and ', @{ $data{ $name } };
print $stringified, "\n";
```

Comment: +1 to avoid the bad practice is much better than to find way to make the bad practice happen

Comment: That is what symbolic references are doing anyway: The evil is in the fact that by using symbolic references, one is treating the program's symbol tables as one's own private hash, which, it, of course, is not. So, **use a hash**. Don't use symbolic references. (I don't think this can be emphasized enough).

Answer (score 4):

See [`perldoc -q "variable name"`](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#How_can_I_use_a_vari):

> Beginners often think they want to have a variable contain the name of a variable. ...

Short answer: Don't. Long answer: Read the FAQ entry (which is also available on your computer). Longer answer: Read MJD's [Why it's stupid to "use a variable as a variable name"](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html) ([Part 2](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname2.html), [Part 3](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname3.html)).

Answer (score 3):

You really shouldn't have to do this, see depesz's answer for the alternative, but...

```
{
    no strict 'refs';
    print join(q{, }, @$name);
}
```

Yes, you can use a string scalar as a variable reference, and it looks up the variable by name.

You can also do this with typeglobs, see the Symbol module for an easy way.

Comment: +1 for the technically correct answer, and for agreeing that you should never do this.

Answer (score 2):

Usually when you think you need to use symbolic references, you will be better served by using a hash (associative array).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %user = (
  'bob' => [qw' jerk perlfan '],
  'mary' => 'had a little lamb',
);

{
  for my $name (qw'bob mary susan'){
    if( exists $user{$name} ){

      if( ref($user{$name}) eq 'ARRAY' ){
        print join( ' ', @{$user{$name}} ), "\n";

      }else{
        print $name, ' ', $user{$name}, "\n";
      }

    }else{
      print "$name not found\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Results in:

```
jerk perlfan
mary had a little lamb
susan not found
```

If you think you **really** need to use symbolic references, this is a safer way to do that.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# can't use my
our @bob = ("jerk", "perlfan");
our $mary = 'had a little lamb';

{
  for my $name (qw'bob mary susan'){
    if( exists $::{$name} ){
      my $ref = $::{$name};

      if( *{$ref}{ARRAY} ){
        print join(' ',@$ref), "\n";

      }elsif( *{$ref}{SCALAR} ){
        print "# $name is not an array, it's a scalar\n";
        print $name, ' ', $$ref, "\n";
      }

    }else{
      print "$name not found\n"
    }
  }
}
```

Which returns:

```
jerk perlfan
# mary is not an array, it's a scalar
mary had a little lamb
susan not found
```

---

You should notice that it is harder to symbolic references safely, which is why you shouldn't use them.

<sub>Unless of course you are an expert doing something advanced.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
no strict 'refs';
print "$name is @$name\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Symbolic references are worth avoiding, but if you really want to use them, they have the same use syntax as regular references: see http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference.