# How can I insert a variables name from a string in Perl?

Tags: perl

I am trying to insert a variable `$font1` below. The variable `$font1` is the name of the font e.g. arial.  I really want it to return `$arial` (or whatever `$font` is) as a variable.

When `$arial` is called, it gets the arial.ttf from a folder on my server via get_fonts.pl.

I have tried everything `\$$font` `'"$font"'` and every possible variation of that.

I even tried `if ($font=="arial"){$font = a ton of different attempts;}`

```
do "get_fonts.pl";
&GetFonts($im);

foreach $key (keys %ENV) {
  if($key !~ /[A-Z]/){
    if ($key="sometext") {
      $text="$ENV{'typetext'}";
      $color="$ENV{'typecolor'}";
      $font="$ENV{'typefont'}";
      $size="$ENV{'typesize'}";

      $string = qq~ $text ~;
      $gd_text = GD::Text->new() or die GD::Text::error();
      $gd_text->set_font($arialb, $size) or die $gd_text->error;
      $gd_text->set_text($string);
      my ($w, $h) = $gd_text->get('width', 'height');
      $y1 = (300 / 6);
      if ($w <= 380) {
        $x1 = ((400 / 2) - ($w / 2));
        $im->stringFT("$blue", $font1, $size, 0, $x1, $y1, "$string");
      }
...
```

Pay no attention to excluded ending brackets..

Notice whare I called `$font1`.. If I call `$arialb` all is fine.

Here is get fonts

```
sub GetFonts {
  my($im) = $_[0];
  $arial = "fonts/arial.ttf";
  # I tried Tons of things here to no avail
  if ($font=="arialb") {
    $font1 = '$arialb'; # and so many different other attempts
  }

  $arialb = "fonts/ariblk.ttf";
  $ariali = "fonts/ariali.ttf";
  $arialbi = "fonts/arialbi.ttf";
  $comic = "fonts/comic.ttf";
  $comicb = "fonts/comicbd.ttf";
  $verdana = "fonts/verdana.ttf";
  $verdanab = "fonts/verdanab.ttf";
  $verdanai = "fonts/verdanai.ttf";
  $verdanabi = "fonts/verdanaz.ttf";
}
```

I also desire to do the same with `$color` but, once `$font` is figured out, I should be able to fiqure that out.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Maybe you won't want to hear this, but what you want to do is a pretty bad idea. See here for discussion: http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html

Comment: @Jimbo: I did a little clean-up on your formatting, but frankly it's a disaster. Can you please clean up the blocks and add some indentation? You can't expect many people to wade through that in an effort to help you.

Comment: One more thing: if you start all your programs with `use warnings;` you get lots of helpful - well - warnings. So you would have seen this: Argument "fonts/arial.ttf" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at <program-name> line <number>.

Comment: Thanks so much. Sorry for the quick paste of the poor code. I will clean it up a bit so all can see what I actually have in mind.
Thanks again for all the great advice..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298035/how-do-i-use-symbolic-references-in-perl/1298392#1298392

Comment: Excellent reading at that link.. Thank you. Yeah, I write stuff out pretty quickly. If the concept works I take the time to clean it up. I am far from a developer and not even good enough to classify as a hack but, I am very careful about doing it right in the long run, should there be one.  I need to learn much more and I have nothing but time, well <=10 more years anyhow...

This is a simple flyer creator for local bands. I was asked to make one. I am giving it a shot. The gui side works well and is simple enough to well, be used by a band.. GD is kicking my butt though..

Comment: Referring to perl.plover.com/varvarname.html in that last one.. 

I will check out the latter too. Thanks..

Comment: Are you using Perl 5? If you are, why are you writing for Perl 4?

Answer (score 10):

If $font equals "arial" and you want to access $arial, you want:

```
${$font}
```

But you almost certainly don't actually want to be doing this. I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do in your code, but it seems like using a hash would be easier and better:

```
$fonts{'arial'} = "/path/to/arial"
```

Also note that the ${$font} example won't work if you're using

```
use strict;
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. The ${$font} really helped. 
The hash is a better idea. I am still learning.
So:
$fonts{'arial'} = "/path/to/arial";
$fonts{'arialb'} = "/path/to/arialb";
What would I do with it?
I guess I am lost there...

Comment: @Jimbo: if you use a hash, you can still refer to the font _by name_ (which is what you want, I think) since the name of the font is the hash's key.

Comment: @Telemachus  I need to dive into using hash in my application. I don't care about calling the font by name and prefer to make it as dynamic and "unusual" as possible. I use timestamps in may cases for things / vars.. 

Your advice here has been quite valuable.. Thanks.. 

I basically have six lines of centered +/- wrapped text each line with indivisual font, color and size assigned over a background image. The gui is html/javascript converted to a png with gd.. hopefully..

Answer (score 3):

Stop wanting that: See [`perldoc -q "variable name"`](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#How_can_I_use_a_vari):

> Beginners often think they want to have a variable contain the name of a variable. ...

Short answer: Don't. Long answer: Read the FAQ entry (which is also available on your computer). Longer answer: Read MJD's [Why it's stupid to "use a variable as a variable name"](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html) ([Part 2](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname2.html), [Part 3](http://perl.plover.com/varvarnacame3.html)).

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, try something similar to:

```
my $f=\$b;  
$b="foo"; 
print $$f;
```

But I do see some issues:

```
if ($font=="arialb") {$font1 = '$arialb'}
```

you shouldn't be doing string comparisons with ==.
You should use the eq operator.

Try this code:

```
$f="sf";
$b="fs";
if($f==$b){
    print "whoops";
}
```

Also, where is $font1 declared?  If it's declared inside the scope of that if statement, you won't be able to see that variable outside of that scope.  I recommend that you use the pragma 
  use strict;
see http://www.perl.com/doc/manual/html/lib/strict.html

Comment: I don't think that `==` compares the length of strings. It always checks for numerical equality. But all strings are numerically equal to 0, so == will test true for any two strings. `perl -e 'print "True\n" if 'hello' == 'what the heck?'';`

Comment: Learn something new every day, especially in edge cases you avoid like the plague.

Comment: @Telemachus: Actually, strings nummify as the value of their leading digits, if any: `perl -e "print '123abc' + 1"` prints "124". Most strings don't have leading digits, though, and thus nummify as 0.

Comment: So much help... I have not written any PERL in over 10 years. I totally forgot about eq. Everyone is great help here...

Comment: @Michael: I actually do know that, but automatically began to assume strings like those in these examples (i.e., without any digits). Thanks for clarifying though.