# How do I create new variables with indexed names in Perl?

Tags: perl

hi i've read some related question non seems tohelp me.
this is a code that will explain what i want.

```
for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
  my $new$i=$i;
  print "\$new$i is $new$i";
}
```

expecting variables to be named `$new0`,`$new1`,`$new2`,`$new3`,`$new4`,`$new5`.
and to have the abillty to use them in a loop like the print command is trying to do.
Thanks

Comment: Would love to know *why* or how you intend to use the result -- wouldn't a hash suffice?

Comment: why don't you use an array? `@news = (); for (...) { $news[$i] = $i; print $news[$i]; }`

Comment: Given that he's using a numeric index, an array would be even better.

Comment: The issue is not whether it is the right data structure. The issue is that creating global variables like this is not a good idea

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549685/how-can-i-use-a-variable-as-a-variable-name-in-perl

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You want to use a [hash or array](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Perl-variable-types) instead.  It allows a collection of data to remain together and will result in less pain down the line.

```
my %hash;
for my $i (0..4) {
    $hash{$i} = $i;
    print "\$hash{$i} is $hash{$i}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Can you describe why exactly you need to do this.
Mark Jason Dominus has written why doing this is not such a good idea in *Why it's stupid to "use a variable as a variable name"*
[part 1](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html), [part 2](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname2.html) and [part 3](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname3.html).

If you think your need is an exception to cases described there, do let us know how and somebody here might help.

Answer (score 9):

You are asking a common question.  The answer in 99.9% of cases is **DON'T DO THAT**.

The question is so common that it is in [perlfaq7: How can I use a variable as a variable name?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#How-can-I-use-a-variable-as-a-variable-name%3f).

See "[How do I use symbolic references in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298035/how-do-i-use-symbolic-references-in-perl)" for lots of discussion of the issues with symbolic references.

Answer (score 2):

use a hash instead.

```
my %h=();
$new="test";
for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
  $h{"$new$i"}=$i;
}
while( my( $key, $value ) = each( %h ) ) {
    print "$key,$value\n";
}
```

Answer (score -4):

if you want to create variables like $newN you can use `eval`:

```
eval("\$new$i=$i");
```

(using hash probably would be better)

Comment: No need for an eval, a symbolic reference is faster and safer.  `${"new".$i} = $i`.  But really, don't do that.