# In Perl, how can I use a string as a variable name?

Tags: perl, string, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use a variable as a variable name in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549685/how-can-i-use-a-variable-as-a-variable-name-in-perl)

Is this doable? I need to change a string into variable.

Example:

If I have a variable like this:

```
$this_is_test = "what ever";
$default = "this";
$default = $default . "_is_test";
```

I want `$default` to take the value of `$this_is_test`.

Comment: I guess I can use a hash to work this out. Yet I was wondering if there is another way.

Comment: @skimnetser: no this wont work. This will give : $default="this_is_test"; which is a string.

Comment: sorry I misunderstood the question, try this: $default= ${$default.'_is_test'};

Comment: This gets asked a lot on SO: [varvarname](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=varvarname). It's also [a Perl FAQ](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#How_can_I_use_a_vari).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298035/how-do-i-use-symbolic-references-in-perl

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Along the lines of [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549685/how-can-i-use-a-variable-as-a-variable-name-in-perl), whenever you find yourself adding string suffixes to a variable name, use a hash instead:

```
my %this = (
    is_test => "whatever",
    is_real => "whereever",
);

my $default = $this{is_test};

print "$default\n";
```

Do **NOT** use symbolic references for this purpose because they are unnecessary and likely very harmful in the context of your question. For more information, see [Why it's stupid to 'use a variable as a variable name'?](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html), [part 2](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname2.html) and [part 3](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname3.html) by [mjd](http://hop.perl.plover.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I used the hash, yet it is not wrong to learn the other ways..By the way it seems that u added an extra _ in the hash key _is_test.

Answer (score 7):

As rafl said, this can be achieved through symbolic references, but they are quite dangerous (they are a code injection vector) and don't work with lexical variables (and should be using lexical variables instead of package variables).  Whenever you think you want a symbolic reference, you almost certainly want a hash instead.  Instead of saying:

```
#$this_is_test is really $main::this_is_test and is accessible from anywhere
#including other packages if they use the $main::this_is_test form 
our $this_is_test = "what ever";
my $default       = "this";
$default          = ${ $default . "_is_test" };
```

You can say:

```
my %user_vars = ( this_is_test => "what ever" );
my $default   = "this";
$default      = $user_vars{ $default . "_is_test" };
```

This limits the scope of `%user_vars` to the block in which it was created and the segregation of the keys from the real variables limits that danger of injection attacks.

Comment: It looks like part of the last sentence got cut-off.

Comment: @Sinan Ünür Thanks, I must have gotten distracted.