# Why I can't use interpolated variable as varname?

Tags: perl

Unfortunatelly, I did not figure out, why `$alfa` remains empty:

```
use 5.014; 
no strict 'refs';

my $berta = 5;
my $gamma = 'berta';
my $alfa = ${$gamma};

say "'$alfa'";
```

Must be something really simple... I expected `$alfa` become `5` here. What I missed?

Comment: Your variable names are interesting. Who's berta? :D

Comment: Of relevance to this discussion: http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html - it is a TERRIBLE idea to ever actually do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Perl, how can I use a string as a variable name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871451/in-perl-how-can-i-use-a-string-as-a-variable-name)

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate of that. That's asking how to do it. This question is why is it not working.

Comment: @simbabque: actually those are spelling names for alphabet letters (example in chess, but in military too), at least in Estonia

Comment: I see. Sounded like Greek with a spelling disorder. :)

Comment: @w.k, Odd. The [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet) is alfa, bravo and golf.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is that the code only works with global variables, not with lexical variables declared using `my`. [See the FAQ](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfaq7#How-can-I-use-a-variable-as-a-variable-name).

```
our $berta = 5;
 my $gamma = 'berta';
say $$gamma; # 5
```

Obviously, this is not a good idea in production code.

Comment: Only `$berta`, the dereferenced variable name, must be global. It is OK for `$gamma` to be lexical.