# Perl: Can I use a variable to name an array?

Tags: perl, reference

Can I use a variable to name an array?

For example:

```
my $input1="AAA";
my $input2="BBB";
my @{$input1};
my @{$input2};
```

Because `$input1=AAA`.

So I want to create an array and its name depends on `$input1`'s value.

And finally it will create array `@AAA` and `@BBB`.

Is this feasible?

Comment: Isn't your code already doing what you ask?

Comment: How do you intend to use __dynamically name defined__ array if you do not know in advance it's name? Perl has [array reference](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut) for such situation.

Answer (score 4):

That would need a "[symbolic reference](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref#Symbolic-references)," a [big no-no](https://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html) for good reasons (also see it [in perlfaq7](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7#How-can-I-use-a-variable-as-a-variable-name), and for example in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1298035/4653379)).  It's a dangerous ancient "feature" which is used only very rarely and for very specific purposes.

Instead, use a hash

```
my %h = ( $input1 => $arrayref1, $input2 => $arrayref2 );
```

`$arrayref` is either a reference to a named array, `\@ary`, or an anonymous array, `[LIST]`.  See about how to create them [in perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref#Making-References), and the rest of the tutorial for working with them.

So now when you need an array by a name stored in a a variable it's `$h{$input1}`, or `$h{AAA}` (if that's the value of `$input1`), what returns the array reference that can be de-referenced to access/add elements.  See the linked `perlreftut`.

---

Note a big difference in how the arrayref is given.  If it is a reference to a named array, then any change in that array is reflected in what we get from the hash (and the other way round)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $in1 = 'A';
my @ary = 5..7;

my %h = ( $in1 => \@ary );

say $h{$in1}->[0];   #--> 5

$ary[0] = 2;

say $h{$in1}->[0];   #--> 2

$h{$in1}->[-1] = 9;
say "@ary";          #--> 2 6 9
```

While if we use an anonymous array, `$in1 => [ LIST ]`, then we get a copy which cannot be changed other than by writing to `$h{$in1}` directly (unless `LIST` itself contains references).

If the `LIST` has references then for an an independent copy one needs a "deep copy."

Comment: @blueFish Given a follow-up question I've added a clarification, with a complete example.